# how to solve a minimization problem when a variable is complex, and an objective function is real?

Tags: optimization

Thank you for your help.
I'd like to solve an optimization problem,
with real-valued objective function and complex-valued control variable

for example, my minimization problem is 
minimize conj(f(x))*f(x) with respect to x (x is a complex variable)

how can I solve this problem??
Is it possible to use First order necessary condition just like as for real optimization problem??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace $x = a + bi$ and work with $a$ and $b$ as your decision variables. Nothing changes